# Remove Ambiguity From Meaning Prime Element, Prime Ideal, Prime for $x^2+2$ in $\mathbb Z_4[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, terminology

Remove ambiguity from  prime element, prime ideal, prime.

---

Here is the context. In $\Bbb Z_4[x]$, given the polynomial $x^2+2$ and asked show it is irreducible, but not prime.

Not sure if in this context it means not a *prime ideal or not prime like a prime integer*.

It is not prime ideal since $$0=(2x-2)(2x+2)\in \langle x^2+2\rangle$$  but $2x-2\notin \langle x^2+2\rangle$ and $2x+2\notin \langle x^2+2\rangle$.

---

Does this mean it is prime element? (like a prime integer)

Comment: Your example works, for $x^2+2$ divides $(2x-2)(2x+2)$ but does not divide either term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any commutative ring $R$ with unity, $p$ is a prime element if and only if $(p)$ is a prime ideal.

Proof: $(p)$ is a prime ideal exactly when $ab\in (p) \iff a\in (p)$ or $b\in (p)$.  But $c\in (p) \iff p \mid c$, so this is equivalent to $p \mid ab \iff p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Comment: Makes sense because from this $x^2+2|0$ where $0=(2x-2)(2x+2)$ but $(x^2+2)\not |(2x-2)$ and $(x^2+2)\not |(2x+2)$. That is the negation of prime.